How do I combine an indicator (RSI) and study (EMA)?
Both scripts works on their own, together they do not.
I want to combine an RSI indicator and EMA (candles chart) in one script. that RSI is under chart, and EMA is plotted in the chart. EMA not in/from RSI values.
I have this for RSI:
//  @version=5
indicator(title="rsi and ema", shorttitle="rsi and ema", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
//
rsiLengthInput = input.int(14, minval=1, title="Length")
rsiSourceInput = input.source(close, "Source")
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsiPlot = plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#AB47BC)
band1 = hline(80, "upper band 1", color=color.new(#F23645, 0))
band2 = hline(20, "lower band 2", color=color.new(#2962FF, 0))

and this for EMA:
study(title="EMA 50/200", overlay=true)
short = ema(close, 50)
longer = ema(close, 100)
plot(short, color = orange)
plot(longer, color = aqua)

If I copy/combine the EMA code under the RSI code, it doesn't work. How do I fix this? I don't want to use two separate codes/indicators. I want this in one.

close, i did it. deleted the study line, copy all other under code from rsi, than add the "force_overlay = true" in plot line of ema --> plot(short, color = orange, force_overlay = true)

We don't close questions when you find an answer. Instead, you should post your solution as an answer.
